# Moving a table from one schema to another in Exasol

Tags: sql, database, exasol

I am trying to move a table which resides in a certain schema to a different schema with the same table name. I have tried the following but they do not work:

```
rename <OLD_SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME> TO <NEW_SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>;
```

The error that appears is:

**SQL Error [42000]: invalid identifier chain for new name [line 1, column 100] (Session: 1722923178259251200)**
and

```
ALTER TABLE <OLD_SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME> RENAME <NEW_SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>;
```

The error that appears is:

**SQL Error [42000]: syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER_PART_, expecting COLUMN_ or CONSTRAINT_ [line 1, column 62] (Session: 1722923178259251200)**

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Exasol documentation](https://docs.exasol.com/sql/rename.htm) there is no way to move table between schemas using `RENAME` statement:

> Schema objects cannot be shifted to another schema with the RENAME
> statement. For example, 'RENAME TABLE s1.t1 TO s2.t2' is not allowed.

I would move the table this way:

```
create table <NEW_SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>
like <OLD_SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>
including defaults
including identity
including comments;

insert into <NEW_SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>
select *
from <OLD_SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>;

drop table <OLD_SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>;
```

Comment: Thanks! this was really helpful :)